# Why geting in request only last question_id value from hidden field...?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, eloquent

[image]

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">

         <div class="wizard-container">

        <div class="card wizard-card" data-color="azzure" id="wizard">
            <div id="clockdiv" class="text-center"></div>
            <script src="js/timer.js"></script> 
            <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">

                <a class="bg-dark">{{$fetchQuestions[0]->name}}</a>
            </div>
            <form action="{{url('get-result')}}" method="get">
                @csrf
                    <div class="wizard-navigation">
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                            @foreach ($fetchQuestions as $key => $question2)
                            <li><a href="#id{{$key+1}}" data-toggle="tab">{{$key+1}}</a></li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                <div class="tab-content">
                    @foreach ($fetchQuestions as $key => $question)  
                    @if($question->type != 'subjective')                      
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="id{{$key+1}}">

                       <h4 class="options">
                        <input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="{{$question->id}}">

                        {{$key+1}}.{{$question->question}}@if($question->type == 'image_type') <img src="{{asset($question->question_image)}}">
                        @endif
                       </h4>
                        <label class="radio">A. {{$question->option_a}}
                          <input type="radio" name="user_answer" value="{{$question->option_a}}">
                          <span class="checkmark"></span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio">B. {{$question->option_b}}
                          <input type="radio" name="user_answer" value="{{$question->option_b}}">
                          <span class="checkmark"></span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio">C. {{$question->option_c}}
                          <input type="radio" name="user_answer" value="{{$question->option_c}}">
                          <span class="checkmark"></span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio">D. {{$question->option_d}}
                          <input type="radio" name="user_answer" value="{{$question->option_d}}">
                          <span class="checkmark"></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>  
                    @else
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="id{{$key+1}}">
                       <h4 class="options">{{$key+1}}.{{$question->question}}</h4>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="answers">
                    </div>   
                    @endif                
                    @endforeach
                </div>
                <div class="wizard-footer">
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <input type='submit' class='btn btn-next btn-fill btn-info btn-wd btn-sm' name='next' value='Save & Next' />
                            <input type='submit' class='btn btn-finish btn-fill btn-info btn-wd btn-sm' name='finish' value='Finish'/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pull-left">
                            <input type='button' class='btn btn-previous btn-fill btn-info btn-wd btn-sm' name='previous' value='Previous' />
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

How to fetch dynamically each questions id and answer id?

Right now I am able to get only answers id, but the question id remains same for each answers after I passed data in controller.
But when I passed question id in hidden field in view, I am able to get unique question id.

And storing questions and answer id in session is preferable or shall i store it in database with each save button click.

Comment: Is this needed, your answer options have a name field/attribute.  This is passed providing one is selected and submitted.  Can you not cross reference that with your question?  So rather than `name = 'your_answer'` something like `name='question_4'`

Answer (score 0):

**You should try this**

```
<input type="hidden" name="question_id[]" value="{{$question->id}}">
```